# how to use this map function in React to call url with images name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
  socialLinks: {
    instagram: 'https://twitter.com/xyz',
    facebook: 'https://facebook.com/xyz',
    linkedin: '#',
  },
```

**how to create a loop so that result should come like this -**

```
<div>
   <a href="https://instagram.com/xyz">
      <image src="instagram.png" />
   </a>
   <a href="https://facebook.com/xyz">
      <image src="facebook.png" />
   </a>
<div>
```

**Note:** *If there is no link of linkedin then no link and image will come*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
<div>
    {
        Object.entries(socialLinks).filter(([k,v]) => v.startsWith("https:")).map(([k,v]) => 
            <a key={v} href={v}>
                <image src={`${k}.png`} />
            </a>
        )
    }
</div>
```

Comment: This fixes my requirement. Thanks Sir. 
Just one warning: 'k' is declared but its value is never read. Any thing missing !!

Comment: @NishaKapoor I guess it's because of this part: `filter(([k,v]) => v.startsWith("https:"))` you can use `filter(kv => kv[1].startsWith("https:"))` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
const SocialMedia = () => {
    let socialLink = {
        instagram: 'https://twitter.com/xyz',
        facebook: 'https://facebook.com/xyz',
        twitter: 'https://twitter.com/xyz'
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {
                Object.keys(socialLink).map((key, index) => {
                    return (
                        <a href={socialLink[key]} key={index}>
                            <image src={key+'.png'} />
                        </a>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```